# Looking for a horror movie involving fish-creatures in an alternate dimension intersecting with ours

Tags: story-identification, horror

I am looking for the movie described below.

copy from [movies.SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/44234/511) but is what I am looking for.

---

I believe this was from 1990s because I recall the images being sleek, like the re-make of Outer Limits. Not grainy. Not cheap film. Not foreign either (like Italy); they spoke English. Pretty sure this was on a cable channel too. The production was slick, but there was also a cheesy feel to it.

**Here is what I recall:**

Two women, one of them in uniform (brunette?) and more sophisticated, the other more relaxed like normal fashion clothes (blonde? skirt?). Both very attractive and in their 20s. We're in the future from the look of the nearly spaceship sleek room (although I don't know that we're actually in space).

The woman in the uniform/pantsuit is explaining about a device that another scientist is working on, perhaps she works for this scientist. I believe the device was like a small arc or perhaps like Star Trek's transporting device, but the idea was that it disturbed/altered the space around it and one did not have to necessarily walk through a gateway or anything. Purple glow was a part of how its effects took place.

The other woman talks her into turning on the device (although it hasn't been working?) and we start to see purple glowing things that eventually look like fish -- strange-looking prehistoric fish that are translucent, one's hand goes right through them like ghosts.

The darker-haired woman explains how dimensions work, that they are on top of each other, so this is all happening at the same time, one doesn't have to walk into another dimension because it is already there and this device allows that to be revealed. She believes the dimension we're looking at to be perhaps like primitive Earth and therefore it is under the ocean.

At a point we see a human-like form, in what appears to be an astronaut uniform type deal (if I recall that correctly) and inside the helmet is a face that looks part fish and part human; sentient, but transparent too like the regular-sized fish. This understandably distracts and amazes them, although the being doesn't say anything or act violently, nor can we see it completely clearly or in full color.

At the same time, one of the fish with the razor sharp teeth seems to get more life-like, less transparent and goes for the face of one of the women.

This causes them to unplug/turn off the device.

Something is said about the fear/possibility that the beings could've perhaps crossed into our world (since the inhabitants should not have seen us?). And I think the darker-haired woman is excited that the device worked so well.

---

I've tracked down so many obscure things in my life that I enjoyed, but I never did get to see the end of whatever this was (late night on a school night). I hope that I remembered things accurately enough. I usually do. Anyway, I'm really stumped and have searched regularly without luck of the right key words...

**It is not "From Beyond", "Xtro", "TerrorVision", or any "Piranha" film despite the alien fish's similarity to them.**

Comment: It does sound a lot like "From Beyond", but it's obviously not exactly the same.

Comment: Yes it does, I watch From Beyond last night, just to make sure. I hope I am not mashing up movies.